# How to get only max value from variable in nested for loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

i need help with this code?
Result is :

- jon 15
- bob 38
- steve 180
- bob 14
- steve 240
- steve 180
- luk   203

but i espected like this :

- jon 15
- bob 38
- steve 240
- luk   203

max value from loop of user

```
 DECLARE

v_z VARCHAR2(50);
max_s  VARCHAR2(50);

BEGIN

max_s := -9999999999999;

FOR i     IN
(SELECT user,
  in,
  out 
  FROM emp)

LOOP
FOR j IN
(SELECT user,
  in,
  out
FROM emp
AND user = i.user
)
LOOP
  IF i.in < j.in AND i.out < j.out AND i.out > j.in AND i.out < j.out AND i.user = j.user 

THEN
    v_z  := ROUND((j.out-i.in),4)*1440 ;

    FOR r                         IN v_z..v_z
    LOOP
      IF r > max_s THEN
        dbms_output.put_line (i.user || ' ' ||r);
      END IF;
    END LOOP;

  END IF;
END LOOP;
END LOOP;
END;
```

table example:

```
  user    in     out
  steve  7:00    9:30
  steve  8:00   10:00
  steve  9:00   11:00
```

And i need result 11:00 - 7:00 for steve
not 10 - 7:00 or 11:00 - 8:00 who also in if condition is true,  i want max value for this user

Answer (score 1):

this can be easily done with single select statement. Clearly no benefit of using PL/SQL and it is definitely slower.

```
select name, max(num) from tbl
group by name
```

Comment: Thanks for query but look again what i need. Thank you

Comment: what is the logic behind this?

Comment: if 7:00<8:00 and 9:30>8:00 and 10:00 > 9:30 then 10:00 - 7:00 result 3*60 = 180            and for this example i need 11:00 - 7:00  then 4*60 240 max value from loop

Answer (score 0):

I would still suggest you're best solution is to use SQL to pull the values rather than loops.  Looks like you want the max(out) - min(in) grouped by user.

Off the top of my head, I'd suggest something like:
  select user, min(in), max(out) from emp group by user;

If you're looking for it do the math:
  select user, out-in from (select user, min(in) as in, max(out) as out from emp group by user);

Comment: I want trim intersection. if 8:00 between 7:00 and 9:30 then 10:00-7:00 result 3h    if 9:00 between 7:00 and 9:30 then 11:00-7:00 result 4h  if 9:00 between 8:00 and 10:00 then 11:00 - 8:00 result 3h.                                                        in this example I want result be 4h if contition is true

Comment: if 9:00 for this example is not between 7:00 and 9:30 or not between 8:00 and 10:00 then result to be 10:00 - 7:00 = 3h

Comment: @Spec, is there any way to convert to a 24 hour clock (so that 7:00pm = 19:00).  How is your data stored (date, number or text in a particular format)?